# SFINAE: 'enable_if' cannot be used to disable this declaration

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, sfinae, type-traits

I want to enable and disable a function declaration in a template class, just based on if the template parameter has one type defined or not for which I use `boost/tti/has_type.hpp`. However, I got the complains from compiler, i.e., **'enable_if' cannot be used to disable this declaration.**

```
#include <boost/tti/has_type.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <set>
using namespace std;

BOOST_TTI_HAS_TYPE(key_type)

template <typename container>
class adapter : public container
{
public:
    using container::container;
public:
    template <typename type = typename enable_if<!has_type_key_type<container>::value,typename container::value_type>::type>
    bool contains(typename container::value_type const & v) { return find(begin(*this),end(*this),v) != end(*this); }

    template <typename type = typename enable_if<has_type_key_type<container>::value,typename container::value_type>::type>
    bool contains(typename container::key_type const & k) { return this->find(k) != this->end(); }
};

int main()
{
    cout << has_type_key_type<adapter<vector<int>>>::value << endl;
    cout << has_type_key_type<adapter<set<int>>>::value << endl;
}
```

How could I resolve it? However, if I change it to similar non-member function template, it works.

```
#include <boost/tti/has_type.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <set>
using namespace std;

BOOST_TTI_HAS_TYPE(key_type)

template <typename container, typename enable_if<!has_type_key_type<container>::value,int>::type = 0>
bool contains(container const & c, typename container::value_type const & v) { return find(begin(c),end(c),v) != end(c); }

template <typename container, typename enable_if<has_type_key_type<container>::value,int>::type = 0>
bool contains(container const & c, typename container::key_type const & k) { return c.find(k) != c.end(); }

template <typename container>
class adapter : public container
{
public:
    using container::container;
public:
    // ...
};

int main()
{
    vector<double> v{3.14};
    set<double> s{2.71};
    cout << contains(v,3.14) << endl;
    cout << contains(s,2.71) << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if I change it to similar non-member function template, it works.

The point is: funtion **template**.

Your code doesn't works because SFINAE works over templates, with test related to the template parameter. Your `contains()` method is a function, inside a template class, but isn't a **template** function.

To make SFINAE works for `contains()`, you have to transform it in a **template** function.

You have seen that works outside the class, but works also inside the class.

For example, with the following trick (caution: code not tested)

```
// .......VVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVV
template <typename C = container, // ................V
          typename std::enable_if<!has_type_key_type<C>::value, int>::type = 0>
bool contains (typename container::value_type const & v)
 { return find(begin(*this),end(*this),v) != end(*this); }

// .......VVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVV
template <typename C = container, // ...............V
          typename std::enable_if<has_type_key_type<C>::value, int>::type = 0>
bool contains (typename container::key_type const & k)
 { return this->find(k) != this->end(); }
```

Observe that the SFINAE test (`has_type_key_type<C>::value`) now involve `C`, the function's template parameter, not `container`, the template parameter of the class.

If you want avoid that `constains()` can be "hijacked" (explicitly setting a type for `C`, different from `container`, you can add a variadic non-type (and unused) template parameter.

For example

```
// .......VVVVVV
template <int..., typename C = container,
          typename std::enable_if<!has_type_key_type<C>::value, int>::type = 0>
bool contains (typename container::value_type const & v)
 { return find(begin(*this),end(*this),v) != end(*this); }

// .......VVVVVV
template <int..., typename C = container,
          typename std::enable_if<has_type_key_type<C>::value, int>::type = 0>
bool contains (typename container::key_type const & k)
 { return this->find(k) != this->end(); }
```

Off Topic: you you can use at least C++14, you ca use `std::enable_if_t`, so

```
std::enable_if_t<has_type_key_type<C>::value, int> = 0
```

instead of

```
typename std::enable_if<has_type_key_type<C>::value, int>::type = 0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot max66, I like your answer very much. I still have a bit confused why compiler doesn't support member functions, maybe compiler can support it, what we do seems like making compiler happy, and what I want is so clear :)

Comment: I mean member functions of a template class.